# Curl automatically display the result?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using php 5.3.2 and when i execute a curl it display the result directly without adding a print or echo function.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$pvars = array('query' => 'ice age', 'orderby' => 'popularity');
$timeout = 30;
$myurl = "http://www.website.com";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

What's wrong with my code and why it displays the result?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By default, the curl extension prints out the result.

You need to enable the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option, like so:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

After that option is enabled, `curl_exec` will return the result, instead.

Comment: "From PHP 5.1.3, this option has no effect: the raw output will always be returned when CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is used".

Comment: with that option it returns null :/

Comment: for later php versions use the it in array     $optArray = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);

Answer (score -1):

after php 5.1 curl always displays results as you can view on the documention. to avoid that simply do:

```
echo "< span style='display:none'>";
$pvars = array('query' => 'ice age', 'orderby' => 'popularity');
$timeout = 30;
$myurl = "http://www.website.com";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

echo"< /span>";
```